# How to work with Phonestate lisner when using Dual sim phone

Tags: android, kotlin

Presently I am working on an android app (Music Player). So I want to pause music on incoming call and play when call end. this code perfectly working with one sim but not in the dual sim. so I want to ask that what change should do in this code to work with multi sim card device

```
class CallListner : PhoneStateListener() {

override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, incomingNumber: String?) {
    when (state) {
        TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE -> {
            Controls.playPauseControl("play")
        }
        TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
            Controls.playPauseControl("pause")
        }
        TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING -> {
            Controls.playPauseControl("pause")
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You should use OnAudioFocusChangeListener instead.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to use this can you explain it how to use it for incoming and outgoing call

Comment: It handles not only incoming and outgoing calls. It handles every possible audio focus change.

Comment: Just follow this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement OnAudioFocusChangeListener in your music service class. and override some methods before initializing media player. it will automatically take of incoming calls, outgoing calls, and all phone notifications.

[For more visit android developers blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/08/respecting-audio-focus.html)